# How do I access the shopping cart directly from a controller action?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

One of the most popular books on ASP.NET Core is "Pro ASP.NET Core 3" by Adam Freeman.

In chapters 7-11, he builds an example application, SportsStore.

[image]

Note the cart information in the upper right corner:

[image]

This shows up in the layout via the following line:

```
<vc:navigation-menu />
```

See [Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-3/blob/master/09%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Cart/End%20of%20Chapter/SportsSln/SportsStore/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml#L22) line 22.

The implementation of the view is at:

[Views/Shared/Components/CartSummary/Default.cshtml](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-3/blob/master/09%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Cart/End%20of%20Chapter/SportsSln/SportsStore/Views/Shared/Components/CartSummary/Default.cshtml)

As well as the C# code at:

[Components/CartSummaryViewComponent.cs](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-3/blob/master/09%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Cart/End%20of%20Chapter/SportsSln/SportsStore/Components/CartSummaryViewComponent.cs)

I know that the persistence of the cart data is setup via the following line in [Startup.cs](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-3/blob/master/09%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Cart/End%20of%20Chapter/SportsSln/SportsStore/Startup.cs):

```
services.AddScoped<Cart>(obj => SessionCart.GetCart(obj));
```

See [Models/SessionCart.cs](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-3/blob/master/09%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Cart/End%20of%20Chapter/SportsSln/SportsStore/Models/SessionCart.cs) for details on `SessionCart`.

Now for the question.

I've added the following method to `HomeController`:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ContentResult CartSize()
    {
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = "cart size here"
        };
    }
```

It's a very simple action method which is intended to simply return the number of items in the cart.

Given the how the cart is implemented in the example project, what's a good way to get the number of items in the cart in the `CartSize` method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the Cart service into your controller and use in your action method

```
  private Cart cart; 

  public MyController(Cart cartService) {

  cart = cartService;
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public ContentResult CartSize()
  {
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = cart.Lines.Count().ToString()
        };
   }
```

Comment: I didn't realize getting access to the cart was as simple as adding a parameter for `Cart` to the controller constructor. It makes me wonder, who takes care of passing in this `Cart` instance? Seems like it's automatically done by ASP.NET Core? I.e. it simply notices that a `Cart` is expected and then passes one? I'm guessing it knows to do this due to this line in `Startup.cs`: `services.AddScoped<Cart>(obj => SessionCart.GetCart(obj));`.

Comment: As an experiment, I removed this line from `Startup.cs`: `services.AddScoped<Cart>(obj => SessionCart.GetCart(obj));`. And indeed, the site doesn't come up after that with the new constructor. So yeah, I guess that line somehow tells ASP.NET Core to provide a `Cart` if it is needed by a constructor.

Comment: Yeah, dependency injection is a fundamental part of asp.net core. It makes apps easier to test and maintain.  Services are usually defined using interfaces. You would create an interface for the dependency implementation and register it in Startup. e.g. services.AddScoped<ICart, Cart>();   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1